# Для чего нужна данная команда reply_markup=markup?

Tags: python, telebot

```
def start(message):
  markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
  buttonA = types.KeyboardButton('Программа тренировок')
  buttonB = types.KeyboardButton('Стоимость')
  buttonC = types.KeyboardButton('Контакты и адреса')

  markup.row(buttonA, buttonB, buttonC)


  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'It works!', reply_markup=markup)
```

Answer (score 1):

`reply_markup=markup` нужен для того, что бы к сообщению привязать клавиатуру.
Подробнее можно прочитать здесь: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup